# how to load pagedown editor with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pagedown

I am fairly new with requirejs. I have managed to use requirejs with AMD modules such as ace editor etc just fine. I saw on stackoverflow that it is theoretically possible to load normal js with requirejs.

After several attempts, research and some frustrations I have failed to load the pagedown editor with requirejs without errors.

Here is my code:

```
       requirejs.config({
        paths: {
          jquery:    "jquery-2.0.2.min",
          bootstrap: "bootstrap.min",
          ace:       "ace/lib/ace",
          prettify:  "pagedown/prettify",
          pdconv:    "pagedown/Markdown.Converter",
          pdsanity:  "pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer",
          pdeditor:  "pagedown/Markdown.Editor",
          pdextra:   "pagedown/Markdown.Extra", 
      },
      shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
      }
    });

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'ace/ace', 'prettify', 'pdconv', 'pdeditor', 'pdsanity', 'pdextra'], 
  function($, Bootstrap, ace, prettyPrint) {
      var input = $('#wmd-input').text();
      var editor = ace.edit("wmd-input");
      var conv = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
      Markdown.Extra.init(conv, {
        extensions: "all",
        highlighter: "prettify"
      });

      var md = new Markdown.Editor(conv);
      md.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", prettyPrint); // google code prettify

      md.run(editor);
      editor.focus();
});
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Markdown.Editor.js:185**

I keep getting that error after each keystroke.
The files are indeed loaded via requirejs but does not work. Is there an easy way to make the pagedown editor work with requirejs or it is not possible.

Any help/advise/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'markdown-converter': "../Scripts/markdown/Markdown.Converter",
        'markdown-sanitizer': '../Scripts/markdown/Markdown.Sanitizer'
    },
    shim: {
        "markdown-sanitizer": {
            deps: ["markdown-converter"],
            exports: "markdown-sanitizer"
        }
    }
});
// create markdown module 
define("markdown",["markdown-converter","markdown-sanitizer"],function(mc, ms) {
    return window.Markdown;
});

define("markdown",function(markdown) {
   var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
   return {
    converter:converter
   }
});
```